# TinyMCE 3.x escaping characters only in IE

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I get different results if I paste the following in HTML mode using **TinyMCE 3.x** ([link](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php))

```
<!--[if !supportLists]-->XI. VACATION
```

IE8 escapes it, heres the generated HTML when it saves:

```
<h4 class="FRSimpleNumbering">&lt;!--[if !supportLists]--&gt;XI. VACATION</h4>
```

Firefox doesn't escape it:

```
<h4 class="FRSimpleNumbering"><!--[if !supportLists]-->XI. VACATION</h4>
```

I haven't been able to find any solution to this and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the tinymce config parameter [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_preprocess).

Using this param you can define a function in which are able to modify the content to be inserted as you need to.

Comment: The problem doesn't just occur when pasting, it happens if I type it in to the HTML box also. I've done more testing and found that if I change the closing tag from ]--> to --> IE will not escape it. So for some reason a comment that ends with ]--> is not recognized properly in this browser only.